# Knapsack variation, Java

Tags: java, recursion, tiles, knapsack-problem

i have this assigment which is a variation of a knapsack problem.
I have a board (Knapstack type, which inner variable is `int[][]` knapsack) and an array of tiles(with size of `n`X`m`, not all of them with the same size). I need to write a function which returns `true` if i can place all the tiles within the knapsack board (without rotating them). For example:
if the tiles dimensions are:[image: dim]

and the board size is 4X4, a possible solution is:[image: board]

this is the code i have thus far:

```
 public boolean insertIntoKnapsack(Tile[] tiles) {
    boolean ans = false;
    ans=solution(this.knapsack,tiles,0,0,0);
    return ans;
}
public boolean solution(int[][] knapsack, Tile[] tiles,int i,int j, int k) {
    boolean ans=false; int a; int b=0;
    if(j>=knapsack.length || k>=knapsack[0].length || i>=tiles.length)
        return ans;
    if(j<knapsack.length && k<knapsack[0].length && i==tiles.length) {
        ans=isValid(knapsack,tiles);
        return ans; }
    for(a=0; knapsack.length-(j+a)>0 && a<tiles[i].getN(); a++) {
        for(b=0; knapsack[0].length-(k+b)>0 && b<tiles[i].getM(); b++) {
            if(knapsack[j+a][k+b]==0)
                knapsack[j+a][k+b]=i+1;
        }
    }
    return ans= solution(knapsack,tiles,i+1,j+a,k) || solution(knapsack,tiles,i+1,j,k+b) || solution(knapsack,tiles,i+1,j+a,k+b);
}
```

the knapsack class is defined as:

```
public class Knapsack {

// Holds the current state of the Knapsack
private int[][] knapsack;

public Knapsack(int n, int m) {
    if(n<=0 || m<=0)
        System.out.println("Bad Input");
    else {
        int knapsack[][] = new int[n][m];
    }
}
```

the function isValid:

```
public boolean isValid(int[][] knapsack,Tile[] tiles) {
    boolean ans=true;
    for(int i=0;i<tiles.length; i++) {
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0; j<knapsack.length;j++) {
            for(int k=0; k<knapsack[0].length; k++) {
                if(knapsack[j][k]==i)
                    count=count+1;
            }
        }
        if(count != tiles[i].getN() * tiles[i].getM())
            ans=false;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

a tile is defined as:

```
public class Tile {
private int n;
private int m;
/*
 * Construct a Tile of size nXm
 */
public Tile(int n, int m) {
if(n<=0 || m<=0) 
    System.out.println("Bad Input");
else {
    this.n=n;
    this.m=m;
}
}

/*
 * Get the Tile's height
 */
public int getN(){
    return n; 
}

/*
 * Get the Tile's width
 */
  public int getM(){
    return m; 
  }

}
```

Not only that i don't know if my solution is correct, whenever i try to test it i get a `NullPointerException`. I tried to change the conditions of the for loops at the solution method, but no matter how i change it i keep getting an error. Can someone please tell me if i'm headed the right way with the solution method or why do i keep getting a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: When you get a Exception thrown at your face, you get a stack-trace to go with it. please use it to identify the line that raises the exception, and add that data to the post. thanks.

Comment: The reason you get an NPE is that you don't initialize the `knapsack` private field. You are defining a local variable and initializing it, but of course, a local variable is discarded by the end of the constructor. As for your solution, for further help, you'll need to comment it and explain your logic.